# nodetool reports much higher load than actual?

Tags: cassandra

I have a ring with 24 nodes, in 2 datacenters. Each node is using Apache Cassandra 2.2.10, and all work generally OK.

But I am seeing HUGE discrepancy between disk space usage and Load as reported by nodetool.

On one of the nodes, I see:

```
=$ nodetool info | grep Load
Load                   : 1.99 TB
```

while the data directory is only:

```
=$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/cassandra/data/
331G    /var/lib/cassandra/data/
```

There are some snapshots in there, but from what I understand, they can increase data usage on disk, but shouldn't increase Load. Which would make sense if load would show 100, and disk space would be 300. But for me - Load is 6 times more than actual disk space usage.

I do not use disk compression, and even checking file sizes as reported by ls - I'm getting ~ 330G on disk.

What am I missing? Why is Load so high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely from a a bug ([CASSANDRA-13738](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13738)) that was fixed in 2.2.11.

Comment: Thanks. If I'd upgrade to 2.2.11 or 2.2.12 - will it be enough to restart cassandra? Or do i need to do something else/more?

Comment: Just rolling restart the nodes after updating.